# Authenticate user from java

Tags: java, authentication, browser

I want to send a request from an authentication server. I need to open a browser to a specific URL, when the user is authenticated, the server sends a response to the Loopback IP address adding parameters to the url.

How can I get these parameters?
To open the browser I'm using:

```
String uri = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/MyProject";
try {
     Desktop d;
     d = Desktop.getDesktop();
     d.browse(new URI(uri));
} catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Use the HTTP Client API instead of opening a browser. https://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.0/api/httpclient/api/index.html

Comment: To expand on @GriffeyDog's comment, you can prompt the user for their username and password, and then you can likely make a POST request to the URI you provided to authenticate the user. You can use the HTTP Client API to make the request.